# Open Tkinter frame based on logical expression result in Python

Tags: python, json, function, tkinter

Hi Tkinter and Python Masters,

Here's my problem.  I'm creating a simple GUI with Tkinter.  I have a background image that I would like to change based on the value of a variable defined in a function that connects to an API (JSON).  The variable will hold one of two values.  Either a 1 or a 2.

What I would like to do in Tkinter (which I'm totally lost on) is have a background image.  If the value of the variable in my API function is 1 show Image1 as the background.  If the value of the variable is 2, show Image2 as the background.

It is a bit messy, but here's my API function

```
def apiconnect(statusvar):


def to_serializable(ticketid):
    return str(ticketid)
url = "http://staging2.apiname.com/ticket_api/tickets"
data = {'ticket_id' : ticketid, 'direction' : 'up'}

headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'J0XxxxxVRy9hMF9Fo7j5'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
requestpost = requests.post(url, headers = headers, json = data)
response_data = requestpost.json()
statusvar = (response_data["status"])
messagevar = (response_data["message"])
json.dumps(url,data)

global accessResult
if statusvar == "successful":
        accessResult = 1
else:
        accessResult = 2
```

Is this possible in Tkinter?  I basically want to reference my variable accessResult in my Tkinter frame, and change the background image based on that value.

Be gentle with me, I'm all new and such

Answer (score 0):

So I'm no expert with Tkinter but if you want to change the background based on only two values why not use a boolean instead so:

```
# Here is where we make the check.
if accessResult == True:
    background_photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Path\\To\\My\First\\\Photo1.png")
else:
    background_photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Path\\To\\My\\Second\\Photo2.png")

backgroundLabel = Label(top, image=backgroundPhoto)
backgroundLabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Good luck! Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that could work.  The problem is that I have Tkinter because of an Entry Widget.  The value the user inputs in this entry widget is what I send to the API.  The data that I use in the entry widget is ticketid in the code below

Comment: data = {'ticket_id' : ticketid, 'direction' : 'up'}

Comment: @David Then you could just do the same thing but replace True with the value you want to compare it to and else with another comparison and maybe a default value just in case at the end? Example: if accessResult == 1: then do something